# Proving that an equation has a unique stable limit cycle

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, nonlinear-analysis

I'm preparing for my exam and I stumbled upon a question and I am a bit lost on how to write the correct solution.

The question goes as follows:

> Prove that the equation $\ddot{x} + \mu(x^{4}-1)\dot{x} + x = 0$ has a
>   unique stable limit cycle when $\mu > 0$. Determine whether it has a
>   limit cycle when $\mu < 0$ and if it has, determine its stability.

I don't really understand how to go about this proof in a logical manner and provide a solution for all of these.

Comment: Try to write this as a system of two first-order ODEs and apply the Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem.

Comment: Of course answer depends on what you have been taught in your course. The answer might be quite trivial if you are allowed to use that this is [Lienard system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard_equation#Li.C3.A9nard.27s_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

One way of establishing the existence of periodic orbits finding a quantity that is conserved along the trajectory of the dynamical system.

Let $\dot{x}=f(x), x\in \mathbb{R}^2$, be your, in this case, autonomous dynamical system.

Let $V(x) = \lVert x \rVert^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2, x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, be a candidate conserved quantity.

Then if you consider the sign of $$\dot{V}=(\nabla_x V)^T\cdot f(x)$$

you will gain great insight on the character of the solution.

Consider also using the Matlab GUI pplane (http://math.rice.edu/~dfield/index.html) which allows you to easily simulate systems like this one.